# Thread local returning null intermittently

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I am using `ThreadLocal` to store a context variable. My component is a SOA - rest component. Problem is the `threadLocal` is that it is returning `null` intermittently. I am sure that I populate it before I use it. I am clearing it from a JAX-RS repsonse filter.

Can the `static final` modifiers lead to this problem? And just by specifying it as a `InheritableThreadLocal` is the `threadLocal` available to all the child threads?

```
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Contains the context object and 
 */
public class ContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> threadLocal = new InheritableThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>>();

    /**
     * Private constructor so that nobody can create an instance.
     */
    private ContextHolder() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the threadlocal with the passed map.
     * 
     * @param context - 
     */
    public static void initConext(Map<String, Object> context) {
        threadLocal.set(context);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the context from this thread.
     * 
     * @return Context
     */
    public static Map<String, Object> getContext() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

    /**
     * Clears the context from the threadlocal.
     */
    public static void clearConext() {
        threadLocal.remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: it comes with java.lang

Comment: Ajay whoops :) Can you clarify that the problem is that the `Map` is `null`, not that the map is returning `null` (i.e. empty)?

Answer (score 2):

The `static final` modifiers should not lead to this problem.  All `ThreadLocal` objects are available to all child threads; it's only their contents that are different on a per thread basis.  An [`InheritableThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html) differs in that child threads' initial values are inherited, rather than initially set to null.  Note that only the initial values are inherited, not subsequent modifications in the parent thread.

Most likely there is a bug in how your code synchronizes when trying to pass values from the parent thread to the child thread.  When dealing with multiple threads, "before" has a very complex and sometimes counterintuitive meaning, especially in earlier versions of Java.